# Python Server Error With Stdin Read, unexpected exception

Tags: python, multithreading, compiler-errors, client-server, stdin

I'm making a python server to keep connected 3 clients. I have finished all and now, when I'm doing the stdin commands for the server (like quit, see (client), etc.) I realized I have an apparently big problem for me:

This is the structure:

```
import sys, os, traceback, optparse
import time, datetime
import random
import socket
import thread
import select

  while True:
        data,addr = dad_sock.recvfrom(UDP)
        if(data != ""):
            print "First_Data:",sys.stdin.readline()
            thread.start_new_thread(MAIN_son,(UDP,data,addr,number_sons))
            number_threads += 1
            print "Second_Data:",sys.stdin.readline()
```

What MAIN_son does is to create a new thread which look for pkg received and keep the clients connected to the server.

And here is my problem:

> Data: ERROR, UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION
> I/O operation on closed file
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "srv.py", line 588, in 
> start()
>
> File "srv.py", line 136, in start
> main()
>
> File "srv.py", line 481, in main
> setup()
>
> File "srv.py", line 164, in setup
> dad_wait(srv.UDP,number_sons)
>
> File "srv.py", line 172, in dad_wait
> print "Data:",sys.stdin.readline()
>
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Line 172 is my first read from stdin() but the program lets me to do it so I think its at the second round of the while when it fails

I need to say that when MAIN_son thread is called starts to print all the pkg info from the client packages. I don't know if this prints can be the cause.

If someone needs more information about the code I'll refresh the question, Thanks

Comment: I can't wrap my head around why a program reads `stdin` because of a udp packet received on a socket. But something closed its `stdin` and that causes the problem. How do you run this program?

Comment: If this is on a thread, it could be that the main program is exiting and that closed stdin.

Comment: @tdelaney I run like python srv.py -d but this -d if for debugg mode, yes, this is on a thread but the main program still alive waiting if more clients arrive. I read in a web that threads can only read stdin one time is it true? Sorry for the delay, thanks for the help

Comment: No, they can read as often as they like, Only the main thread gets keyboard interrupts so they may remain blocked on the read even when they should be closing. And I'm not completely sure what happens if multiple threads are reading at once. But this should keep working as long as its the only thread using stdin.

Comment: When I asked how you ran it, I was curious if it was just from the command line and whether you did anything to put it in background mode. I'm trying to figure out what closed stdin.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit strange, I only have one thread waiting to see what I introduced by stdin and the error only appears if I call the 2nd thread who keep the clients.